How to fix classification tree that is taking too long?
I am using ESS data to see what predicts the party vote choice of immigrant-origin Italian respondents. I will be running a GLM regression, but, would like to use a classification tree to to identify the most important variables, to then use them as covariates.
What my data looks like:
str(ess_vote)

'data.frame':   1626 obs. of  632 variables:
$ isco08          : int  1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 1212 ...
$ name            : chr  "ESS10e03_2" "ESS10e03_2" "ESS10e03_2" "ESS10e03_2" ...
$ essround        : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
$ edition         : num  3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 ...
$ proddate        : chr  "02.11.2023" "02.11.2023" "02.11.2023" "02.11.2023" ...
$ idno            : int  14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 14130 ...
$ cntry           : chr  "IT" "IT" "IT" "IT" ...
$ dweight         : num  1.72 1.72 1.72 1.72 1.72 ...
$ pspwght         : num  1.29 1.29 1.29 1.29 1.29 ...
$ pweight         : num  1.95 1.95 1.95 1.95 1.95 ...
$ anweight        : num  2.52 2.52 2.52 2.52 2.52 ...
$ prob            : num  0.0000603 0.0000603 0.0000603 0.0000603 0.0000603 ...
$ stratum         : int  2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 2124 ...
$ psu             : int  14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 14352 ...
$ nwspol          : int  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
$ netusoft        : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ netustm         : int  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 ...
$ ppltrst         : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ pplfair         : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ pplhlp          : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ polintr         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ psppsgva        : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ actrolga        : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ psppipla        : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ cptppola        : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ trstprl         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ trstlgl         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ trstplc         : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ trstplt         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ trstprt         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ trstep          : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ trstun          : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ trstsci         : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
$ vote            : chr  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
$ prtvtdit        : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ contplt         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ donprty         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ badge           : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ sgnptit         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ pbldmna         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ bctprd          : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ pstplonl        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ volunfp         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ clsprty         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ prtcleit        : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ prtdgcl         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ lrscale         : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ stflife         : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ stfeco          : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ stfgov          : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ stfdem          : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ stfedu          : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ stfhlth         : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ gincdif         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ freehms         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ hmsfmlsh        : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ hmsacld         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ euftf           : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ lrnobed         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ loylead         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ imsmetn         : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ imdfetn         : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ impcntr         : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ imbgeco         : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ imueclt         : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ imwbcnt         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ happy           : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
$ sclmeet         : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ inprdsc         : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ sclact          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ crmvct          : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ aesfdrk         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ health          : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ hlthhmp         : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ atchctr         : int  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
$ atcherp         : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ rlgblg          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ rlgdnm          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ rlgblge         : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ rlgdnme         : int  66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 ...
$ rlgdgr          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ rlgatnd         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ pray            : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ dscrgrp         : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ dscrrce         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrntn         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrrlg         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrlng         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscretn         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrage         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrgnd         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrsex         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrdsb         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscroth         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrdk          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrref         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ dscrnap         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ dscrna          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ ctzcntr         : chr  "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
\[list output truncated\]

My variable of interest is all_votes, a factor variables:
table(ess_vote$all_votes)

                     + Europa                             Altro 
                           49                                34 
                 Forza Italia                 Fratelli d'Italia 
                           55                                96 
                    La destra                              Lega 
                            7                               123 
              Liberi e Uguali                Movimento 5 Stelle 
                            9                               716 
     Partido Democratico (PD)        Popolo delle Libertà (PdL) 
                          467                                36 

Sinistra Ecologia e Libertà (SEL)                          SVP-PATT
19                                15
Here is my code:

#1- split sample and create folds

ess_vote <- ess_merged[complete.cases(ess_merged$all_votes), ]

ess_vote <- ess_vote %>%
  select_if(~!all(is.na(.)))

set.seed(seed)

split_data_vote <- initial_split(ess_vote, prop = 0.7)
data_folds_vote <- vfold_cv(ess_vote, v = 3) #3 fold validation

# Specify training and testing sets
migrants_train_vote <- training(split_data_vote)
migrants_test_vote <- testing(split_data_vote)

#2 - Build a recipe (formula and pre-processing steps)
tree_recipe_vote <- recipe(migrants_train_vote, all_votes ~ .) %>%
  step_rm(psu, idno, dweight, essround, proddate, isco_title, `ISCO-88`, isco08, isco08p, continent_code) %>%# Remove specified variables
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% # Remove predictors with zero variance
  step_novel(all_predictors(), -all_numeric()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% # Dummy codes categorical variables
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) # Normalize all numeric variables

#3- Specify the model; same as above
tree_spec_vote <- decision_tree() %>%
  set_engine("rpart") %>%
  set_mode("classification")

#4- Define workflow; same as ridge
tree_workflow_vote <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(tree_recipe_vote) %>%
  add_model(tree_spec_vote)

#Step 5: Define the tuning grid
tree_grid_vote <- grid_regular(
  cost_complexity(),
  min_n(),
  trees(),
  levels = 3)

#Step 6: Tune the model 
set.seed(seed)
tree_tune_vote <- tree_workflow_vote %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = data_folds_vote,
    grid = tree_grid_vote,
    control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))

best_tree_vote <- 
  tree_tune_vote %>% select_best()

# Step 9: Finalize the workflow
tree_final_vote <- tree_workflow_vote %>%
  finalize_workflow(parameters = select_best(tree_tune_vote, 'rmse'))

# Step 10: Fit the final model
tree_last_fit_vote <- tree_final_vote %>%
  last_fit(split=split_data_vote)

tree_last_fit_vote %>% 
  collect_metrics()

plot_tree_vote <- tree_last_fit_vote%>%
    extract_fit_parsnip() #Need this to be able to plot the decision tree

# Step 13: Plot the final tree
rpart.plot(plot_tree_vote$fit,
           type = 1,
           main = "Figure 5: Final Decision Tree",
           roundint = FALSE,
           fallen.leaves = TRUE,
           box.palette = "RdBu",
           nn = TRUE)

The error occurs at step 6 (tuning), it either takes weeks to run, or gives me the following error message:
Error in estimate_tune_results():
! All models failed. Run show_notes(.Last.tune.result) for more information.
Backtrace:

tree_tune_vote %>% select_best()
tune:::select_best.tune_results(.)
tune:::show_best.tune_results(x, metric = metric, n = 1)
tune::estimate_tune_results(x)
Error in estimate_tune_results(x) :

show_notes(.Last.tune.result)

unique notes:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
! There are new levels in a factor: NA.
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
! decision_tree() was unable to find an outcome.
ℹ Ensure that you have specified an outcome column and that it hasn't been removed in
pre-processing.
However, I can see that "all_votes" is present in tree_workflow_vote[["pre"]][["actions"]][["recipe"]][["recipe"]][["var_info"]][["variable"]] . So I don't understand where the error is coming from.
I also tried this method, and let it run overnight and it still hadn't gotten the results.
fit <- rpart(all_votes ~ .,
   method="class", data=ess_vote)

plot(fit, uniform=TRUE)

Here is my SessionInfo, and let me know if you need anything else/if you have any suggestions!!
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gridExtra_2.3           ISCO08ConveRsions_0.2.0 nuts_1.0.0             
 [4] leaflet_2.2.1           cowplot_1.1.3           stargazer_5.2.3        
 [7] knitr_1.45              huxtable_5.5.6          data.table_1.15.2      
[10] countrycode_1.5.0       profvis_0.3.8           RColorBrewer_1.1-3     
[13] ggspatial_1.1.9         ggrepel_0.9.5           viridis_0.6.5          
[16] viridisLite_0.4.2       reshape2_1.4.4          see_0.8.2              
[19] MASS_7.3-60.0.1         nnet_7.3-19             tictoc_1.2             
[22] vdemdata_13.0           readxl_1.4.3            haven_2.5.4            
[25] raster_3.6-26           sp_2.1-3                modelsummary_1.4.5     
[28] tidytext_0.4.1          themis_1.0.2            textrecipes_1.0.6      
[31] rpart.plot_3.1.2        rattle_5.5.1            bitops_1.0-7           
[34] ranger_0.16.0           parttree_0.0.1.9004     plotly_4.10.4          
[37] pscl_1.5.9              texreg_1.39.3           rpart_4.1.23           
[40] sjPlot_2.8.15           randomForest_4.7-1.1    gghighlight_0.4.1      
[43] ggeffects_1.5.0         ggiraphExtra_0.3.0      sf_1.0-15              
[46] yardstick_1.3.0         workflowsets_1.0.1      workflows_1.1.4        
[49] tune_1.1.2              rsample_1.2.0           recipes_1.0.10         
[52] parsnip_1.2.0           modeldata_1.3.0         infer_1.0.6            
[55] dials_1.2.1             scales_1.3.0            broom_1.0.5            
[58] tidymodels_1.1.1        patchwork_1.2.0         readstata13_0.10.1     
[61] brant_0.3-0             janitor_2.2.0           gtsummary_1.7.2        
[64] gt_0.10.1               vip_0.4.1               lubridate_1.9.3        
[67] forcats_1.0.0           stringr_1.5.1           dplyr_1.1.4            
[70] purrr_1.0.2             readr_2.1.5             tidyr_1.3.1            
[73] tibble_3.2.1            ggplot2_3.5.0           tidyverse_2.0.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] splines_4.3.2        cellranger_1.1.0     hardhat_1.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.4     
  [5] globals_0.16.2       lattice_0.22-5       crosstalk_1.2.1      insight_0.19.8      
  [9] backports_1.4.1      SnowballC_0.7.1      magrittr_2.0.3       sass_0.4.8          
 [13] rmarkdown_2.26       jquerylib_0.1.4      yaml_2.3.8           DBI_1.2.2           
 [17] minqa_1.2.6          ipred_0.9-14         lava_1.8.0           tokenizers_0.3.0    
 [21] listenv_0.9.1        terra_1.7-71         units_0.8-5          performance_0.10.9  
 [25] parallelly_1.37.1    svglite_2.1.3        codetools_0.2-19     xml2_1.3.6          
 [29] tidyselect_1.2.0     lme4_1.1-35.1        broom.helpers_1.14.0 jsonlite_1.8.8      
 [33] e1071_1.7-14         ellipsis_0.3.2       survival_3.5-8       iterators_1.0.14    
 [37] emmeans_1.10.0       systemfonts_1.0.5    foreach_1.5.2        tools_4.3.2         
 [41] Rcpp_1.0.12          glue_1.7.0           prodlim_2023.08.28   xfun_0.42           
 [45] mgcv_1.9-1           withr_3.0.0          ROSE_0.0-4           fastmap_1.1.1       
 [49] boot_1.3-30          fansi_1.0.6          digest_0.6.34        timechange_0.3.0    
 [53] R6_2.5.1             estimability_1.5     colorspace_2.1-0     utf8_1.2.4          
 [57] generics_0.1.3       class_7.3-22         httr_1.4.7           htmlwidgets_1.6.4   
 [61] pkgconfig_2.0.3      gtable_0.3.4         timeDate_4032.109    GPfit_1.0-8         
 [65] furrr_0.3.1          janeaustenr_1.0.0    htmltools_0.5.7      mycor_0.1.1         
 [69] kableExtra_1.4.0     gower_1.0.1          snakecase_0.11.1     rstudioapi_0.15.0   
 [73] tzdb_0.4.0           uuid_1.2-0           nlme_3.1-164         nloptr_2.0.3        
 [77] cachem_1.0.8         proxy_0.4-27         sjlabelled_1.2.0     KernSmooth_2.23-22  
 [81] parallel_4.3.2       pillar_1.9.0         grid_4.3.2           vctrs_0.6.5         
 [85] xtable_1.8-4         lhs_1.1.6            evaluate_0.23        mvtnorm_1.2-4       
 [89] cli_3.6.2            compiler_4.3.2       crayon_1.5.2         rlang_1.1.3         
 [93] ppcor_1.1            future.apply_1.11.1  modelr_0.1.11        classInt_0.4-10     
 [97] plyr_1.8.9           sjmisc_2.8.9         ggiraph_0.8.9        stringi_1.8.3       
[101] assertthat_0.2.1     tables_0.9.17        munsell_0.5.0        lazyeval_0.2.2      
[105] bayestestR_0.13.2    pacman_0.5.1         Matrix_1.6-5         sjstats_0.18.2      
[109] hms_1.1.3            future_1.33.1        highr_0.10           bslib_0.6.1         
[113] DiceDesign_1.10     


Tuning may take a long time if there are many hyperparameters being examined. The number of models being trained and evaluated is the number of rows in your tune_grid. I would suggest reducing the number of hyperparameters you examine in your tree_grid_vote dataframe.
I would also suggest that if your model is going to be a glm, then it may be advisable to use a method like L1-penalised glm (eg glmnet package) to do feature selection. Using a tree-based method for feature selection may identify nonlinear/nonmonotonic features, which a glm model would not be able to use as easily as a decision tree.
